# How to remove null or undefined properties for sequelize return instance

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

By using sequelize, return a [object SequelizeInstance:User]

The instance with the following value

```
   {
     "id":1,
     "first_name":null,
     "last_name":null,
     "username":"abc"
   }
```

Try to use lodash 4 omitby

```
const cleanObject = _.omitBy(obj, _.isNil);
```

not working.

Try another solution

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    if (!obj[k]) {
        delete obj[k];
    }
});
```

still not working

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the solution. Convert to Json before passing to omitby

```
let result = this.userModule.findOne();
const cleanObject = _.omitBy(result.toJSON, _.isNil);
```

Comment: `raw: true` on the sequelize query will return the results as JSON too